# How to ensure fat stays in meat/fish?

Tags: meat, oil, fat

I'm looking for a cooking method which retains fat and oil.  When I grill, boil, simmer etc I notice most of the oil leaves the meat.

Which method is best to ensure fats and oils are retained during cooking?

I heard that if you marinade in olive oil before grilling that will prevent fat from coming out.  Is it true?

Can I grill or bake at lower temperatures to get desired result?  will the meat still be cooked to the safe temperature if done this way?

Comment: Why do you say *most* of it leaves the meat? Are you just seeing a lot of liquid come out, and assuming that's most of the fat? The liquid that comes out is mostly water, especially from less fatty cuts of meat.

Comment: Well I cannot say it is the majority of fat, but it's obviously a lot cos if you've boiled, grilled etc then put it in liquid in the refrigerator it becomes solid.

Comment: If you just want to use the fat, you could add a bit of flour, some water, to make a gravy?  or else use something else to sop it up (bread, potatoes)? It'd still get eaten, but seems like it'd be easier than trying to keep it inside

Answer (score 3):

Fat will melt at high temperature (temperature depends on the type of fat); there is not real way to get away from that.

If you pan fry a steak, the fat will melt into the pan; that is why most people suggest a good "marbling" of fat in the meat so not all of it will melt away.

One cooking method, that I think will help keep most of the fat in the meat is low temperature vacuum cooking.

Put the meat in vacuum sealed bag and cook at low temperature (check instructions) in a water bath; after a while, the meat will be cooked and the fat will not have melt away; just finish in a pan to sear the outside.

See:
https://www.thekitchn.com/sous-vide-cooking-this-is-the-best-steak-ive-ever-had-197056

Comment: 130-140°F is the temperature to render fat which is also the temperature of medium rare.  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/36638/at-what-temperature-will-the-fats-on-meat-render